# Rules for hexblades in Ravenloft in 3.5

Tags: dnd-3.5e, ravenloft

D&D3.5's hexblade class uses curses and other malign abilities.

Are there (licensed) official rules for **how the hexblade's abilities would work and be affected in Ravenloft 3.5** (published by Arthaus/White Wolf)? If so, where can I find them? If not, are there good unofficial rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can provide a half answer:
No there aren't official rules.
If I recall correctly Ravenloft was an OGL product and since the hexblade was not covered in the OGL there could not be any official support.  From reading the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravenloft) entry on Ravenloft it sounds like Arthaus had to excise a fair amount of setting material initially due to licensing issues with other portions of the Wizards IP from the beginning.